# Getting column names in pandas that equal a value for a given row

Tags: pandas

I have a table like this:

```
  Scen  F1  F2  F3  F4
0   S1   1   0   1   0
1   S2   0   1   0   1
```

and want to search by `Scen` and return the column names that == 1 for that row, e.g. for `S1` I require `F1, F3` as the result.

I've tried the following, and can get the result by hard coding `df_col[0]` , but need to be able to do this dynamically.

What's the best way to do this?

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Scen': ["S1", "S2"],
     'F1': [1, 0],
     'F2': [0, 1],
     'F3': [1, 0],
     'F4': [0, 1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def get_features(df, col_name):
    df_col = df[(df.Scen == col_name)].T
    feats = (df_col[(df_col[0] == 1)]).index.to_list()

    print(feats)
    return feats

get_features(df, "S1")
get_features(df, "S2")
```

EDIT:

Based on [RichieV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692898/richiev) 's answer, this works:

```py
def get_features(df, col_name):
    df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
    df = df.melt('Scen')
    df_scen = (df['variable'].loc[(df['Scen']==col_name) & (df['value']==1)])
    return (list(df_scen))
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].dot(','+df.iloc[:,1:].columns).str.lstrip(',')` This is what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-hot decoding operation. When you encode to ones you pivot a column, so now we need to melt it back.

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan) # get rid of zeros, they only fill spaces
df = df.melt('Scen').drop('value', axis=1)
```

Now df has four rows and two columns (scen and variable) with repeated scen rows for each corresponding feature. You can use df as it is or group by scenario and gather features in a list.

```
df = df.groupby('Scen').apply(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, not sure it's the most efficient

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Scen': ["S1", "S2"],
     'F1': [1, 0],
     'F2': [0, 1],
     'F3': [1, 0],
     'F4': [0, 1]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def get_features(df, col_name):
    df_col = df[(df.Scen == col_name)].T
    df_feats = df_col.loc[df_col[df_col.columns.values[0]] == 1]
    return (list(df_feats.index))

s1_list = get_features(df, "S1")
s2_list = get_features(df, "S2")
print(s1_list)
print(s2_list)
```

```sh
['F1', 'F3']
['F2', 'F4']
```